# Changing string with escaped Unicode to normal Unicode

Tags: python, unicode

I've got a string which looks like this, made up of normal characters and one single escaped Unicode character in the middle:

`reb\u016bke`

I want to have Python convert the whole string to the normal Unicode version, which should be `rebūke`. I've tried using `str.encode()`, but it doesn't seem to do very much, and apparently decode doesn't exist anymore? I'm really stuck!

**EDIT**: Output from repr is `reb\\\u016bke`

Comment: Could you print the 5th character? It is `0` or `k`? Possibly it is just the console that show you the `\u` notation (so check how to have UTF-8 console, there are many questions here). Else the question is legit (unescaping a string)

Comment: Post the output you get when you do a `print(repr(your_variable_here))`

Comment: So the full correct string should be 'rebūke', meaning the unicode character 'ū' must be represented as '\u016b'. I.e. the fifth character should therefore be a 'k'. Can Python pick out the '\u016b' in the middle of the string and convert it to unicode?

Comment: The output from repr is 'reb\\u016bke'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I try reproducing your issue:

```
s="reb\\u016bke";
print(s);
# reb\u016bke
print(repr(s));
# 'reb\\u016bke'
print(s.encode().decode('unicode-escape'));
# rebūke
```

Comment: Aaah fantastic! Thanks so much!